# How can I make Tomcat interpret a jar library?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, jboss, gson

I'm working at a company that doesn't belong to the IT field, but its processes and data depend on a web application. My responsibility, as part of the IT team, is to update this application due to changes in the processes. The problem I have is that the former developers, that made this app with JAVA JDK 6, for some unknown reason, left a development environment on JBOSS and a production environment on Tomcat without the documentation to generate a war file on Tomcat.

Given this, I decided to substitute the .class and .xhtml files, which worked at the beginning. My problem is that one of my developments depends on the gson library, which JBOSS can interpret by copying the jar file to the server/default/lib, but when trying this same process with Tomcat (copying the jar file to lib folder from Tomcat or lib folder from the project), it doesn't work.

Could someone offer me an alternative so the project deployed on Tomcat identifies gson library?

Thanks beforehand for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Putting in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the deployed webapp should work.

Restart your server after you add your jar.

Comment: and I guess a restart of tomcat would probably be necessary

Comment: Some additional reference material [ https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath ]